# Issue with Process Exited

Tags: c#, process, exit, exit-code

lets say I have a process with the ID 1234. This process is running before my application runs.

I have this code:

```
        Process app = Process.GetProcessById(1234);
        MessageBox.Show(app.MainWindowTitle);
        app.Exited += this.methodShowsMessageBox;
```

Now, when I compile and run the app, it gets the process and shows the main window title. However when i close process 1234, the app.Exited does nto fire... why is this? And how would i get it to fire?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please note that the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) states that `EnableRaisingEvents` must be set to `true` before this event will fire.

Answer (score 3):

By default, for performance reasons, the Process class does not raise events. If you want the Process object to watch for Exited and raise that event, you need to set its [EnableRaisingEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) property to true.

> There is a cost associated with
>   watching for a process to exit. If
>   EnableRaisingEvents is true, the
>   Exited event is raised when the
>   associated process terminates. The
>   procedures that you have specified for
>   the Exited event run at that time.
>
> Sometimes, your application starts a
>   process but does not need to be
>   notified of its closure. For example,
>   your application can start Notepad to
>   allow the user to perform text
>   editing, but make no further use of
>   the Notepad application. You can
>   choose to not be notified when the
>   process exits, because it is not
>   relevant to the continued operation of
>   your application. Setting
>   EnableRaisingEvents to false saves
>   system resources.